# How do i passed data into modal using ajax codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, codeigniter

Im trying to solve this problem for few hours already im trying to fetch a data from database into modal to update it but im having difficulty in fetching the data when i click the button that will trigger to display the modal it doesnt show i tried many things already this is my code

Script

```
    function show_profile(){
        $.ajax({
        type     : 'ajax',
        url      : '<?php echo site_url('pages/profile_data')?>',
        async    : false,
        dataType : 'json',
        success  : function(data){
            var html = '';
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){

                html += '<tr>' + 

                       '<th>'+'Faculty Name   :  '+ '</th>' + '<td>' + data[i].faculty_name+'</td>'+ '</tr>' + '<tr>' + 
                       '<th>'+'Faculty Type   :  '+ '</th>' + '<td>' + data[i].faculty_type+'</td>'+ '</tr>' + '<tr>' + 
                       '<th>'+'Email Address  :  '+ '</th>' + '<td>' + data[i].email_address+'</td>'+ '</tr>' + '<tr>' + 
                       '<th>'+'Department Name:  '+ '</th>' + '<td>' + data[i].department_name+'</td>'+ '</tr>' + '<tr>'+

                       '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm item_edit"'">Edit</a>'+' '+
                       '<th>'+'<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm item_update" data-faculty_name="'+data[i].faculty_name+'" data-faculty_type="'+data[i].faculty_type+'"data-email_address="'+data[i].email_address+'"data-department_name="' + data[i].department_name+ '">Update</a>' + '</th>' + '</tr>';      
            }
            $('#show_data').html(html); 
    }
});
      }


  $('#show_data').on('click','.item_update',function(){

            var faculty_name = $(this).data('faculty_name');
            var faculty_type = $(this).data('faculty_type');
            var email_address = $(this).data('email_address');
            var department_name = $(this).data('department_name');

            $('#Modal_update_info').modal('show');
            $('[name="faculty_name_edit"]').val(faculty_name);
            $('[name="faculty_type_edit"]').val(faculty_type);
            $('[name="email_address_edit"]').val(email_address);
            $('[name="department_name_edit"]').val(department_name);

  });


       $('#btn_update').on('click',function(){


        var faculty_name = $('#faculty_name_edit').val();
        var faculty_type = $('#faculty_type_edit').val();
        var department_name = $('#department_name_edit').val();
        var email_address = $('#email_address_edit').val();

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : "<?php echo site_url('pages/update_profile')?>",
            dataType : "JSON",
            data : {faculty_name:faculty_name, faculty_type:faculty_type, department_name:department_name, email_address:email_address },
            success: function(data){
               $('[name="faculty_name_edit"]').val("");
               $('[name="faculty_type_edit"]').val("");
               $('[name="department_name_edit"]').val("");
               $('[name="email_address_edit"]').val("");
               $('#Modal_update_info').modal('hide');
               show_profile();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Model

```
        public function profile_list()
    {
        $faculty_name = $this->session->userdata('faculty_name');

        $query = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('faculty')
        ->where('faculty_name', $faculty_name)
        ->join('department','department.department_id = faculty.department_id')
        ->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

      function update_profiledata(){
            $faculty_name = $this->input->post('faculty_name');
            $faculty_type = $this->input->post('faculty_type');
            $department_name = $this->input->post('department_name');
            $email_address = $this->input->post('email_address');
            $this->db->where('faculty_name', $faculty_name);
            $result = $this->db->update('faculty');
            return $result;
        }
```

Controller

```
    public function profile_data()
{
    $data = $this->page_model->profile_list();
    echo json_encode($data);
}

    public function update_profile()
{
    $data = $this->page_model->update_profiledata();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

View

```
  <div class="card-header p-3 mb-2 bg-dark text-white text-align:center">
         My Profile
         </div>
         <div class="card-body">
         <table class="table table-striped" id="mydata">
         <tbody id="show_data" style="text-align:left">

                    </tbody>

         </table> </div>
```

```
       <form>



    <div class="modal fade" id="Modal_update_info" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update User Information</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-6 col-form-label"><b>Faculty Name</b></label>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input type="text" name="faculty_name_edit" placeholder="faculty_name" id="faculty_name_edit" class="form-control">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-6 col-form-label"><b>Faculty Type</b></label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="faculty_type_edit" id="faculty_type_edit" class="form-control" placeholder="faculty_type" readonly>
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-6 col-form-label"><b>Department</b></label>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input type="text" name="department_name_edit" id="department_name_edit" class="form-control" placeholder="department_name" readonly>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-6 col-form-label"><b>Email</b></label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="email_address_edit" id="email_address_edit" class="form-control" placeholder="email_address" required="email ">
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>


  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" type="submit" id="btn_edit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: am not sure what you are trying to do do in this line $('#show_data').on('click','.item_update',function() but is should be something like $(document).on('click','.target_element',function(){}); please review that line

Comment: im trying to get the data of item_update btn